# Send output from bash from multiple scripts to a single file

Tags: bash

I'm having this type of structure:
main.sh

```
  main() {
    code ...
    source file1.sh
  }

  main | tee mylogfile.txt
```

file1.sh

```
  code here
  echo "\033[0;31mBALBLABLA\033[0m"
  source file2.sh
  ...
```

file2.sh

```
   apt-get install -y packages # hide this from terminal but send to my log file
   ansible-playbooks -i hosts playbook.yml # hide this from terminal but send to my log file
```

filex.sh

```
   code
   source main.sh
   source filey.sh
   ...
```

What I'd like to do is to not display nothing from file 2 on the screen but to send the output to the same file as the one from main.sh `mylogfile.txt' and be there present on the correct order
[ as I can send that output to a different file and then concatenate them but I'll not have the order on parts executed so this is not helpfull]

Is it this possible?

Regards,

LE:
What I'm trying to acoomplish is to send the logs in real time [disable buffering from scripts] as I'm having set -e inside main.sh script.

With that, if something is causing problems my script will be killed and I'll not be able to see the errors in mylogfile.txt

The solutions posted in comments did not work, unfortunately

Comment: if the error logging is the only issue, then maybe you can use a trap functionality. The function gets executed on the specified error codes. Every time the script exists , the trap function will be called and you can use that function to push the final error on which the script exited to the logfile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think with the requirement of keeping order in log file, it's only possible with getting the `source file1.sh` out from main.

```
log=mylogfile.txt

main() {
   code...
} 
main | tee -a $log
source file1.sh >>$log 2>&1   # to have errors in log
```

Or putting the log handling inside the main and splitting it to blocks

```
log=mylogfile.txt
main() {
   { 
      code... 
   } | tee -a $log
   source file1.sh >>$log 2>&1
   { more code ... } | tee -a $log
}  

main  # runnig...
```

Comment: For the moment this seems to be what I wanted. Let me 2,3 more days to play with that idea. Thanks

Comment: I ended up using this one with some changes on my code... Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can insert markers into your output that allow you to filter. Just make sure that the markers are unique strings that never appear in your output otherwise.

```
...
echo "!print off!"
# commands whose output should be logged but not printed
echo "!print on!"
...

main |
tee >(grep -vxE '!print (off|on)!' > mylogfile.txt) |
sed '/^!print off!$/,/^!print on!$/d'
```

[`grep -vxE`](https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=grep%20-vxE%20%27%21print%20%28off%7Con%29%21%27) deletes the markers `!print off!` and `!print on!` so that they don't show up in your log. `sed` additionally deletes all lines between those two markers.

Comment: Wow ... that seems to work. Could you please explain what grep -vxE does and sed?

Comment: How can I prevent even these messages from the screen like:
`Warning: apt-key output should not be parsed (stdout is not a terminal)`
or
`Extracting templates from packages: 100%`
or
`WARNING: Running pip as root will break packages and permissions. You should install packages reliably by 
 using venv: https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/venv`

Comment: Sounds like they are printed to stderr instead of stdout and therefore are not filtered or logged. To remove them, use `main 2> /dev/null | ...` or `{ commands that produce them; } 2> /dev/null`.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm having a problem with this. Let's say I display a big menu and after I chose an option it will fail because I created a bad function. When the script will exit my log file will show just a part of the menu and the error will not be displayed. Why what is redirected to the file is somehow delayed?

Comment: Pipes and some programs have buffers for efficiency. When you terminate the command prematurely, buffered data may be lost. You can try to disable the buffering with `unbuffer` or `stdbuf`, see [Turn off buffering in pipe](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/25372/187122).

Comment: unfortunately this is working only if I'm running the script as: `stdbuf -i0 -o0 -e0 main.sh` but I can't do so

Comment: If `stdbuf` can be used, but just not before calling the script, then try to move the `stdbuf` inside your script by using something like `export -f main; stdbuf ... bash -c 'main' "$0" "$@"`. Other than that, I cannot help you any further. You can un-accept this answer and maybe edit your question to attract other users.

Comment: Maybe you have some idea why this is not working:
```type main | sed '1,3d;$d' > /tmp/.main.sh;
stdbuf -i0 -o0 -e0 bash /tmp/.main.sh |
    tee >(grep -vxE '!print (off|on)!' > mylog.txt) |
    sed '/^!print off!$/,/^!print on!$/d'```

Comment: Sorry I don't know. I don't even know what *"is not working"* means here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232903/discussion-between-astingengo-and-socowi).

Answer (score 0):

When you don't require `source`, you can try it differently.
Change `file1.sh` in

```
code here
echo "\033[0;31mBALBLABLA\033[0m"
./file2.sh >> mylogfile.txt
...
```

And use the `-a` option in the `tee` in `main.sh`

```
main() {
  code ...
  source file1.sh
}
main | tee -a mylogfile.txt
```

You don't want to write the name of the logfile in two scripts, so use a variable

Change `file1.sh` again:

```
code here
echo "\033[0;31mBALBLABLA\033[0m"
./file2.sh >> "${mylogfile}"
...
```

And change `main.sh`

```
main() {
  code ...
  source file1.sh
}
export mylogfile="mylogfile.txt"
main | tee -a "${mylogfile}"
```

When you need the `source`, you can wrap it in a function. When you don't want to change things with stdbuf, you can get your output "in the wrong order" (`file2.sh` writing the next line in the logfile before `tee` had time for processing the pipe). You can change `file1.sh` again and add an artificial flush with a `sleep`:

```
wrap_file2(){
   sleep 0.1
   source file2.sh
   sleep 0.1
}

code here
echo "\033[0;31mBALBLABLA\033[0m"
wrap_file2.sh >> "${mylogfile}"
...
```

Comment: I can't change the source in bash. Don't remember right now why but the code needs to use source instead of bash filename.sh

Comment: I made a wrapper function using `source`. I needed to add a `sleep` for better synchronisation of the loggings.